# Pydantic: Define a default field as a function of another

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm using pydantic dataclasses to create a non-mutable dataclass that contains a `name`, a `label` and an `id`. I want to be able to specify the label when creating a `MyClass` object or give a default label that depends on the value of `name`.

The current implementation only works when `label` is part of the input arguments is the following:

```py
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class MyClass
    name: str = Field(default="class_name")
    label: str = Field(default=None)
    id: str = Field(default_factory=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()))

    _validate_uuid = field_validator("id")(uuid_error)

    @field_validator("label")
    def set_default_label(cls, v, values):
        if v is None:
            v = foo(values["name"])
        return v
    ...
```

Using this code, we can trigger two different behaviours:

```py
MyClass(name="object_name", label=None)
```

returns the **right** object:
`MyClass(name="object_name", label=foo("object_name"),...)`

but if we rely on the default value for `label`, e.g. using this:

```py
MyClass(name="object_name")
```

then the validator is not called and label stays `None`:

`MyClass(name="object_name", label=None)`

Comment: Why not just use `__post_init__`?

Comment: The issue is that once the dataclass is created, the fields cannot be modified, you get a `FrozenInstanceError`

Comment: Consider whether you want to repeatedly validate the same *fixed* default value everytime you instantiate `MyClass`. It makes more sense to simply ensure that the default value is valid to begin with. (Besides, your "validator" isn't validating a value so much as *replacing* it.)

Comment: I need to account for two cases, the one where we provide a label, and the second where we do not provide anything and it has to be inferred from a valid name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without additional configuration default values are not validated in Pydantic. So you have to pass the corresponding config option to the definition of the data class. Check out the following example:

```py
from pydantic import Field, field_validator, ConfigDict
import uuid
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

def foo(name):
    return name + "_label"


@dataclass(config=ConfigDict(validate_default=True))
class MyClass:
    name: str = Field(default="class_name")
    label: str = Field(default=None)
    id: str = Field(default_factory=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()))

    @field_validator("label", mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def set_default_label(cls, v, info):
        if v is None:
            v = foo(info.data["name"])
        return v

print(MyClass())
```

Which prints:

```
MyClass(name='class_name', label='class_name_label', id='fda6cbe7-a756-4e93-9924-0cd024f59251')
```

In addition I think it is good to be explicit about the validation mode, and declaring the validation as a class method.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Exactly, `validate_default=True` is what I was looking for, thanks for your help!